# Having problems trying to redirect user if they are logged in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, redirect, routes

I’m using Rails 4.2.5.  If a user is logged in, I want to redirect them if they visit http://localhost:3000/ to http://localhost:3000/user_objects .  So I have added this to my config/routes.rb file

```
  constraints(AuthenticatedUser) do
    root :to => "user_objects"
  end
  root 'pages#index'
```

Then I have this file in lib/authenticated_user.rb …

```
class AuthenticatedUser
  def self.matches?(request)
    user_signed_in?
  end
end
```

Unfortunately, when I’m logged in, and I access http://localhost:3000/, I get this error

```
NameError

uninitialized constant AuthenticatedUser
```

Any idea how I can redirect the user to the suggested page if someone is logged in?

**Edit:** My config/routes.rb file is as follows ...

```
  resources :user_objects, except: :update do
    member do
      patch :create
      put :create
    end
    get :find_by_user_object_and_day, on: :collection
    get :find_totals, on: :collection
  end

  get "users/edit" => "users#edit"
  resources :users

  root 'pages#index'

  get '/auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create'
  get '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'
  delete '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'
```

Comment: what's the helper method for object_user when you `rake routes`?

Comment: it got a little messy trying to cut and paste that, but I pu tin my config/routes.rb file, which is very basic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the controller action for whatever root is, you can just say:

```
if current_user
  redirect_to user_objects_path #look up the rails helper    
end
```

Comment: Would this go in my application_controller file?  For rake routes, I have "root GET    /  pages#index" for the root page

Comment: It would go in the index action of the pages controller

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Scoping.html#method-i-constraints) on `constraints` recommends putting custom constraint classes to `lib/constraints`.

Anyway, for the class to be recognized in `routes` **you should have it autoloaded**. Add the directory where the constraint resides to the list of autoloaded directories in `application.rb`:

```
# config/application.rb
# Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
config.autoload_paths += %W[...
                           #{config.root}/lib/constraints]
```

Comment: I moved that file to a constraints directory and added yoru code, but when I visit http://localhost:3000/, it is still tryihng to render pages#index instead of redirecting to 'root :to => "user_objects".'

Comment: I see, I admit I got so distracted by the "uninitialized constant" error that I forgot to follow your root issue :). On a second thought I would also choose @toddmetheny's approach.